# Why does this not run into an infinite loop?

Tags: python, namespaces, program-entry-point, python-module

This code was picked up from an answer in this thread [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

```
# Suppose this is foo3.py.

def functionA():
    print("a1")
    from foo3 import functionB
    print("a2")
    functionB()
    print("a3")

def functionB():
    print("b")

print("t1")
print("m1")
functionA()
print("m2")
print("t2")
```

I think the code is executed as follows (when executed as main python3 foo3.py):
1. Prints t1
2. Prints m1
3. Enters functionA and prints a1
4. Imports functionB from foo3, thus running foo3 again. Goes back to step 1
Can you help me correct my analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not "run `foo3` again", it runs the **`foo3.py`** script again. The first time `foo3.py` was running was to produce the module `__main__`, the second time to produce the module `foo3.py`.

The behaviour is in fact (almost) *as if* you had a file named `__main__.py` and another named `foo3.py` **both** with these exact same content and you then run `python __main__.py`. This is what is happening.

Only, Python fakes it so that *it looks as if the program started from a script named* `__main__.py` no matter what the actual Python file was. The only telltale sign to contrary is that `__file__` would tell the filename of the actual script, i.e. `/spam/ham/eggs/foo3.py`.

---

The reason why it does not go to an infinite loop is that `import` looks for a module with the given name in `sys.modules` - if it is already present there it does not execute any new files. Upon startup Python will create an entry for `__main__` in `sys.modules`, and the code of the startup script (`foo3.py`) is executed within the scope of this module.

Then when it executes the statement `import foo3` it will check if `foo3` has an entry in `sys.modules`. As it is not there, a *new* empty module named `foo3` is created, placed into `sys.modules`, and the code of `foo3.py` is executed within the scope of this **new empty module**.

It eventually executes the `import` **2nd** time. This time there *is* `foo3` in `sys.modules`, so importing does not create or load any more scripts, just returns the already-loaded module.

To get the "infinite" loop you can *delete* the already-imported module reference from `sys.module` prior to importing `foo3` again:

```
import sys

def functionA():
    print("a1")

    if 'foo3' in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules['foo3']

    from foo3 import functionB
    print("a2")
    functionB()
    print("a3")

def functionB():
    print("b")

print("t1")
print("m1")
functionA()
print("m2")
print("t2")
```

And when run you'll get

```
  [....]
  File ".../foo3.py", line 7, in functionA
    from foo3 import functionB
  File ".../foo3.py", line 17, in <module>
    functionA()
  File ".../foo3.py", line 7, in functionA
    from foo3 import functionB
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! If I want to learn more about how python works and get a good grasp over the language, do you suggest any good resources?

Comment: @PrashanthRavichandar reading the source code would be a good one - although it might be a bit similar to jumping into a river without any gear and trying to learn to swim. Just my two cents.

Comment: Reading source code will lead to cargo culting, i.e. you're repeating the patterns you're seeing in other people's code without due understanding. For Python, the **official** Python tutorial, PEPs and various books are good.